# JWT token for both API and azure vault key for OAUTH policy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, jwt

Can I use Authorization token that I get from Azure Ad app to call other registered app as the Authorization to get secrets in azure key vault? So that I just need to get one access token instead of 2?

Comment: I think you can use refresh token to exchange another access token for other resources with changing scope , details see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Comment: Your mark list shocks me. If you accept answers on time, people will be more glad to assist you : )

Comment: @JasonPan That makes sense !!

Comment: @JasonPan what is mark list?

Comment: @StanleyGong thanks for the documentation. I just use the same azure ad app to fetch the token. :)

Comment: @StanleyGong Can you tell him？

Comment: @Kai950, so your issue has been solved now ?

Comment: @StanleyGong yes yesss! Thank youuu!

Comment: @Kai950, glad to know that your issue has got solved. I have summarized the solution as an answer Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )  If you accpet answers on time, people will be more gald to assist you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get another access token for other resources, you can use a refresh token to exchange another access token for other resources with changing scope, details see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token).